# How to check if a picture box contains a certain image using an IF statement

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I am trying to check if a PictureBox contains a certain image, the way I am trying to do it seems like it would work in my head, however, does not, i am not sure if there is any other way to check if the picturebox on the form contains a certain image.

```
private void user_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    //If statement to check if the forms picture box contains a certain image 
    if (pictureBox1.Image == Resources.user_male_white_red_brown)
    {
         this.Hide();
         UserProfile User = new UserProfile();
         User.ShowDialog();
         User.pictureBox1.Image = Resources.user_male_white_red_brown;
         this.Close();
    }
    else if (pictureBox1.Image == Resources.user_female_olive_orange)
    {
          this.Hide();
          UserProfile User = new UserProfile();
          User.ShowDialog();
          User.pictureBox1.Image = Resources.user_female_olive_orange;
          this.Close();
     }
}
```

Comment: An image (picture) is an object and Resources is a factory which creates a new image each time so it will never match one in any picture box.  Use a variable to track which image is shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although PictureBox Image might be identical as the one in the resources but they are not the same as reference. (Imagine like you have 2 copy of the same photo although their image is the same but they are 2 separate photos).

There are a few ways you can do it, one of them (a simple one) is to set the picturebox Tag to a relevent value whenever setting its image and compare that value instead of comparing images:

```
User.pictureBox1.Image = Resources.user_male_white_red_brown;
User.pictureBox1.Tag = "user_male_white_red_brown";
```

And then:

```
if((string)User.pictureBox1.Tag == "user_male_white_red_brown")
{
     // your logic
}
```

This way you need to set PictureBox tag whenever you set its image.

Another way would be loading all images from resources to an array and setting the PictureBox image from the array, this way as the reference of both images (picturebox.Image and the image item in the array) are the same comparison would work for images but I think the first solution is easier.